# Adjust WPF Popup Position when Window Size is changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I am trying to make a popup on a button click , I am achieving the desired result by using Popup control,but problem I am facing is the placement.
While popup is opened and the screen size is changed , that popup would remain at the same place and this looks ugly.
Any idea how to change the popup placement according to screen size as well ?
The code snippet is follows:

```
<Popup x:Name="AdvancedFlyout" IsOpen="{Binding FlyoutVisibility}" Placement="Left" HorizontalOffset="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=btnAdvanced}" VerticalOffset="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=btnAdvanced}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to hook up to some events to be able to manually write the code to move your Popup according to the screen size changing. You can bind directly to SystemParameters.WorkArea.PrimaryScreenWidth if you wish, the problem is that upon opening of the Popup, the position is then calculated and the popup placed so even if you set bindings the thing just gets placed upon opening.

```
"{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidthKey}}"
```

hook up the event

```
yourWindow.SizeChanged += ( o, args ) =>
                            {
                                YourPopup.HorizontalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth / 2 - YourPopup.Width / 2;
                                YourPopup.VerticalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight / 2 - YourPopup.Height / 2;
                            };
```

If you wan to wire into screen size changed events in the handler just write some code like this:

```
        YourPopup.HorizontalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth / 2 - YourPopup.Width / 2;
        YourPopup.VerticalOffset = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight / 2 - YourPopup.Height / 2;
```

This will place in center screen.
Good luck and I hope this helps.
Please mark answer if this helps you.